# Programatically show Delete button on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I want to display "Delete" button on `UITableViewCell` the way it is seen when we swipe from right to left on the cell. I need to show this button on tap on another button inside the cell.

I tried following approaches by far:

1. Adding the cell content view into a scroll view and then shifting
   the cell by 80 points to left on tap on the button inside the table
   view. Delete button is also part of the scroll view to extreme right off screen.
2. Adding a UIButton to the end of the UITableView Cell (initially hidden with frame having X starting the right edge of the screen). Then shifting
   the cell by 80 points to left on tap on the button inside the table
   view.

While #1 does not show up the button #2 shows it well. But I am not able to tap on the button as it is off frame from its super view.

Any idea how to go about it?

This is how I am shifting my cell content (this method is in my custom cell class.):

```
- (void)showCellDeleteButton {
    if (self.isDeleteMode) {
        return;
    }

    self.cellDeleteButton.hidden = NO;
    self.isDeleteMode = YES;
    [self disableDeleteItemButton];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        CGRect cellFrame = self.frame;
        cellFrame.origin.x -= 80.0;
        self.frame = cellFrame;
    } completion:nil];
}
```

This is my Delete button with #2:

[image]

Comment: In your show `showCellDeleteButton`, you are calling `[self disableDeleteItemButton];`. Is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, thats intentional to disable the button that shows the Delete button on right so user could not tap on it again.

Comment: Oh I thought that function was for the red delete button! Instead of shifting the entire cell why don't you put all your subviews inside of a `UIView` that will be the full content view of the cell with the delete button hidden behind it. And move **this** `UIView` instead of the entire cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this like that.
 1. Add UIView in cell's content view with equal width of cell's content view and design according to your requirement.
 2. Then add a Button with Delete design into cell's content view not the other view.
 3. When you want to show your delete button simply move your view by 80 points to the left, don't move cell and cell's content view.

Comment: When I do so, the button inside my cell tap on which I want to move the content is not tappable. The tap event goes to table controller in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: add a click event for your delete button and in click function you can your job.

Comment: :). That I am already doing. When button is added directly to cell' content view, it triggers the action and not when its added to another view which is further added as subview to cell content view.

Comment: Its because when you move your subview in cell' content, then delete button goes out of view's touch area that he can't pick any touch event.
Hope you understand.

Comment: I understand. How do I make the button sense the touch while still being part of a UIView and not directly a sub view of cell content view?

Comment: Whats your requirement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131490/discussion-between-abhinav-and-user3305573).

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:**
I don't think you can modify default swipe gesture of cell. You can only enable or disable the gesture. So that means you cant play much with default delete button  shown on cell swipe. What you can do is make tableView editable on your button click and then you can show delete button. For example

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
-(void)deleteButtonTapped:(UIButton *)deleteButton{
    [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}
```

**Approach 2:**
Design your own custom cell which can show custom buttons and will look like the default. Please refer below link.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views